# PHP input value pass to loop

Tags: php, linux

I am new in PHP and i came across following problem. I want to write a simple form which takes multiple input fields and pass them other page to print those value in multiple lines for example see following screen shot. My question is i want to use loop so i don't need to write all variable name and multiple line.. how do i use loop to achieve following solution?

[image]

This is the output of after submit..

[image]

Here is the code of index.php

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Build File: <input type="text" name="1bname">
WAR File: <input type="text" name="1wname">
Study: <input type="text" name="1study">
Bug: <input type="text" name="1bug">

<br>
Build File: <input type="text" name="2bname">
WAR File: <input type="text" name="2wname">
Study: <input type="text" name="2study">
Bug: <input type="text" name="2bug">

<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>

<pre>{ ignore(FAILURE) { build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["1bname"]; ?>", WARFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["2wname"]; ?>", STUDY: "<?php echo $_POST["1study"]; ?>", BUG: "<?php echo $_POST["1bug"]; ?>" )}},


<pre>{ ignore(FAILURE) { build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["2bname"]; ?>", WARFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["2wname"]; ?>", STUDY: "<?php echo $_POST["2study"]; ?>", BUG: "<?php echo $_POST["2bug"]; ?>" )}},

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best option would be to use arrays, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="bname[]" />
<input type="text" name="wname[]" />
<input type="text" name="study[]" />
<input type="text" name="bug[]" />
```

Then you could process them all with a simple loop:

```
<?php $count = count($_POST['bname']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) { ?>
  <pre>{ ignore(FAILURE) { build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["bname"][$i]; ?>", WARFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["wname"][$i]; ?>", STUDY: "<?php echo $_POST["study"][$i]; ?>", BUG: "<?php echo $_POST["bug"][$i]; ?>" )}}
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: could you please give me example with loop? I meant how to use array with loop, I am totally new in PHP

Comment: I have one more thing to ask. create on fly input fields? In front page i would like to put `Add` button so i can create as many as i want on fly rather than hard code?

Comment: @Satish you can achieve that using javascript :)

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if you give example :)

Comment: @Satish It'd be better if you asked that as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

billyonecan's answer is right, but there's not much explanation so I'll add some examples.

Imagine an HTML form that looks like this:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" />
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" />
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" />
</form>
```

This will come through as an array into php, as if you've done this:

```
$_POST['first_name'] = array("thomas", "billy", "jeoff");
```

So you can loop through this array to get the different values:

```
foreach($_POST['first_name'] as $name){
    echo $name."<br />"; // this will print a list of names
}
```

You can obviously take these principals and use them for your specific case. :)

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Used ***foreach*** loop in welcome.php with defining arrays for inputs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        fields = 0;
        function addInput() {
            var con = document.getElementById('text');
            if(fields != 10)
            {
                con.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "Build File: <input type=\"text\" name=\"bname[]\">WAR File: <input type=\"text\" name=\"wname[]\">Study: <input type=\"text\" name=\"study[]\">Bug: <input type=\"text\" name=\"bug[]\"><br />");
                fields += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                con.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', "<br />Only 10 instances allowed.");
                document.form.add.disabled=true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post" name="form">
    Build File: <input type="text" name="bname[]">
    WAR File: <input type="text" name="wname[]">
    Study: <input type="text" name="study[]">
    Bug: <input type="text" name="bug[]">

    <br />
    Build File: <input type="text" name="bname[]">
    WAR File: <input type="text" name="wname[]">
    Study: <input type="text" name="study[]">
    Bug: <input type="text" name="bug[]">
    <br />
    <div id="text">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<input type="button" onclick="addInput()" name="add" value="Add more inputs" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And in welcome.php :

```
<html>
<body>
<?php foreach($_POST['bname'] as $id => $value) { ?>
<pre>{ ignore(FAILURE) { build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["bname"][$id]; ?>", WARFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["wname"][$id]; ?>", STUDY: "<?php echo $_POST["study"][$id]; ?>", BUG: "<?php echo $_POST["bug"][$id]; ?>" )}},</pre>
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice, How do i dynamically add field as many i want rather than static entry? I meant i would like to put `add` button so i can add more input like on-fly

Comment: @Satish I updated the post with new ability to add mpre input fields.

Comment: I have tired your code, i can see `Add more inputs` button but its doing nothing. its not adding new lines..

Comment: @Satish I modified it again, test it.

Comment: Great!!!!! Thanks a lot.. last question. when i put something in field and add new filed its blank out all fields anyway we can preserve values?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would be better off by using array() method since it would take care on what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Extending on billyonecan's answer, your server-side script could be something like this:

```
$bname_array = $_POST['bname'];
$wname_array = $_POST['wname'];
$study_array = $_POST['study'];
$bug_array = $_POST['bug'];

for($i=0; $i<count($bname_array); $i++){

// your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you have a number id before all input area, you can do:

```
<?php
$totalRow=2;
for($i=0, $i<$totalRow,$i++)
{
?>
<pre>{ ignore(FAILURE) { build( "Deploy",  BUILDFILE: "<?php echo $_POST[$i."bname"]; ?>", WARFILE: "<?php echo $_POST[$i."wname"]; ?>", STUDY: "<?php echo $_POST[$i."study"]; ?>", BUG: "<?php echo $_POST[$i."bug"]; ?>" )}},

<?php
}

?>
```